# Updated Ubuntu 16.04 and networking stopped working

Tags: networking, 16.04

After an update of 16.04 (which updated the kernel to 4.4.0-67) I lost all networking options. To resolve the issue I booted into the old kernel version 4.4.0-66. Then the issue went away.
To be clear this impacts all networking. Both wired and wireless. I'm not sure if this is systemd/upstart related, but it sucks to have to enter the advanced boot options every time I reboot to select the kernel.

Comment: What kind of update was done if I may ask, `upgrade`, or `dist-upgrade`?

Comment: I was just a plain upgrade. I didn't jump from 16.04 when the issue took place. I've been running 16.10 for a while.

Comment: Please do a `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Turns out I was running 16.04 LTS and not 16.10. After doing a dist-upgrade to 16.10 everything seems to be working again. Not sure what happened to 16.04, but I'm happy with how it turned out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Good to hear about that, :)...